# Dimensional Analysis; how to show this?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, dimensional-analysis

I've been tasked to find a model to represent the flow rate of a pipe. I've done this, and gotten the following dimensionless variables as per the Buckingham $\pi$-theorem:

$$\pi_1 = \frac{r^4\cdot\frac{dz}{dp}}{q\cdot\mu}, \pi_2 = \frac{q\cdot\rho}{r\cdot\mu}$$

$$G(\pi_1,\pi_2) = 0$$

What I am stuck on now is trying to show that you can recover $\pi_1$ from a special case of this G function. So far, I'm thinking of using the Implicit Function Theorem (IFT) to represent the function G as the following:

$$\pi_1 = f(\pi_2)$$

Where f is some function. This is where I'm stuck; I don't know what function I can use to show that it is necessarily true that in one special case you can recover the first dimensionless variable. Through use of the BHT, I did manage to get the first part of this question as the following by assuming one real root, shown below:

$$q = \frac{r^4\cdot\frac{dz}{dp}}{\mu\cdot\kappa}, \kappa \in \mathbb{R}$$

And thus I am wondering what kind of function I should try to show that you can in fact recover the first dimensionless variable as a special case of the overall function of the dimensionless variables.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, I'm truly stuck here.

Comment: Is $\mathrm{d}z / \mathrm{d}p$ the inverse of the pressure gradient ($z$ being the direction along the pipe axis)? And $\mu$ is just the viscositiy in units, say, $stress \cdot time$ ?

Comment: Dz/dp is the pressure drop per unit length, and u is the viscosity yes.

Comment: Is it not $\mathrm{d} p / \mathrm{d}z$ is the pressure drop per unit length, if $p$ stands for pressure?

Comment: Have those characters the wrong way around, thank you for spotting that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would comment rather than answer this, but I don't have enough reputation.

I assume you obtained $G(\Pi_1,\Pi_2)$ from a dimensionless product of the form $\big(\Pi_1\big)^a\big(\Pi_2\big)^b,$ so that $G(\Pi_1,\Pi_2)$ is a function consisting of the two independent products $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$? Well by considering $(a,b)=(1,0)$ we just get the single independent and dimensionless product $\Pi_1$, so you've recovered your $\Pi_1$, right? Perhaps this is much too simplistic of an outlook on it, but I don't really see how you're going to find $f$, since $f$ is supposed to be experimentally determined (unless you were given other information that you haven't stated).

Comment: No no, that's true, I originally did it exactly like this but was told that it would be better to find some function which would return it; so basically I can just say that the first product is returned in the case wherein the first power is 1 and the second 0 and be done with it?

Comment: Also, once youve obtained your \Pi_1, since it's dimensionless, you can just apply the Buckingham Pi theorem on it as usual, and then get your real root k, etc?

Comment: If you were explicitly told to find a more specific function, then perhaps you should continue trying to do that, although I'm not sure how to help there

Comment: What do you mean by that? So I consider the case where the powers kill off the second variable then just repeat what I did for the first to make it $q = ...$?

Comment: The question literally reads "Show that you can recover the result of part (a) as a special case of the result
of part (b)." where part B is that function of two dimensionless variables

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking

Comment: So literally just consider that case and repeat the one real root step and it should be fine?

Comment: Have you ever heard of the implicit function theorem?

Comment: Yes, it was shown but not explained/proven, we were told that it would be a good idea to make use of it however for this

Comment: If you truly *must* use the implicit function theorem, perhaps rearrange for q in terms of your other variables and $f(\pi_2)$. Then choose your $f$ so that you will recover $\frac{r^4 dp/dz}{k\mu}$. Try $f(x)=(1/k)*x^0=1/k$. This seems superfluous, since your product is kind of the trivial case. If you had have had different $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ which didnt have exactly what you want contained inside one of them, the implicit function theorem could be quite useful to retrieve your $q=\frac{r^4 dp/dz}{k\mu}$

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose to use the reciprocal of $k$ here?

Comment: only because you had $k$ on the bottom in your question. Just wanted to keep things consistent :)

Comment: Alright so just to really drive this home, I can really just write $\frac{r^4\cdot\frac{dz}{dp}}{q\cdot\mu} = f(\pi_2) = x^0+k = k$ and rearrange for q just like I did at the start and finally show that this is in fact the special case?

Comment: No. Well first of all $f(x)=k$, not the reciprocal. My bad. And then, $\pi_1=f(\pi_2)$ by IFT. We know $\pi_1=\frac{r^4 dz/dp}{q\mu}$, so we can rearrange for $q$ and get $q=\frac{r^4 dz/dp}{f(\pi_2)\mu}=\frac{r^4 dz/dp}{k\mu}$ which is the original result? 

(Personally I would just use the (1,0) thing, but if you were asked to use IFT, then I suppose you could do it like this).